# Get the latest record from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to know the most recent record in a collection. How to do that?

Note: I know the following command line queries works:

```
1. db.test.find().sort({"idate":-1}).limit(1).forEach(printjson);
2. db.test.find().skip(db.test.count()-1).forEach(printjson)
```

where idate has the timestamp added.

The problem is longer the collection is the time to get back the data and my 'test' collection is really really huge. I need a query with constant time response.

If there is any better mongodb command line query, do let me know.

Answer (score 187):

This is a rehash of the previous answer but it's more likely to work on different mongodb versions.

```
db.collection.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Comment: `db.collection.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1}).pretty()` if you want it to look nice

Comment: So, what's the difference with this order : ```db.collection.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).pretty()```

Comment: @Digits what performance impact will it have if we place limit at the end also how last record is fetched when your are limiting the output to just one document and it must be the top document in collection.

Comment: Nice answer. I tried like this :
  db.collection("name of collection").find({}, {limit: 1}).sort({$natural: -1})

Comment: For anyone using AWS DocDB: `Query failed with error code 303 and error message 'option $natural is not supported' on server docdb`.  Hopefully that feature comes soon.

Comment: In Python/PyMongo: docs = dbCollectionQuotes.find({}).limit(1).sort([('$natural',  pymongo.DESCENDING)]) and it returns a cursor, so you have to do loop through even though there is only one.

Answer (score 63):

This will give you one last document for a `collection`

```
db.collectionName.findOne({}, {sort:{$natural:-1}})
```

`$natural:-1` means order opposite of the one that records are inserted in.

**Edit**: For all the downvoters, above is a Mongoose syntax,
mongo CLI syntax is: `db.collectionName.find({}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1)`

Comment: Your syntax seems to be wrong.  I cannot get it to work as you have it.  What does work is:
'db.punchdeck.findOne( {$query:{}, $orderby:{$natural:-1}} )'

Comment: not sure, why all the downvotes - this code works perfectly for me, and is fast

Comment: @dark_ruby You query returns error "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: sort: { $natural: -1.0 }",

Answer (score 26):

Yet another way of getting the last item from a MongoDB Collection (don't mind about the examples):

```
> db.collection.find().sort({'_id':-1}).limit(1)
```

**Normal Projection**

```
> db.Sports.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb5f82dea65504b456ab12"), "Type" : "NFL", "Head" : "Patriots Won SuperBowl 2017", "Body" : "Again, the Pats won the Super Bowl." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb6011dea65504b456ab13"), "Type" : "World Cup 2018", "Head" : "Brazil Qualified for Round of 16", "Body" : "The Brazilians are happy today, due to the qualification of the Brazilian Team for the Round of 16 for the World Cup 2018." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb60b1dea65504b456ab14"), "Type" : "F1", "Head" : "Ferrari Lost Championship", "Body" : "By two positions, Ferrari loses the F1 Championship, leaving the Italians in tears." }
```

**Sorted Projection ( _id: reverse order )**

```
> db.Sports.find().sort({'_id':-1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb60b1dea65504b456ab14"), "Type" : "F1", "Head" : "Ferrari Lost Championship", "Body" : "By two positions, Ferrari loses the F1 Championship, leaving the Italians in tears." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb6011dea65504b456ab13"), "Type" : "World Cup 2018", "Head" : "Brazil Qualified for Round of 16", "Body" : "The Brazilians are happy today, due to the qualification of the Brazilian Team for the Round of 16 for the World Cup 2018." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb5f82dea65504b456ab12"), "Type" : "NFL", "Head" : "Patriots Won SuperBowl 2018", "Body" : "Again, the Pats won the Super Bowl" }
```

`sort({'_id':-1})`, defines a projection in descending order of all documents, based on their `_id`s.

**Sorted Projection ( _id: reverse order ):** getting the latest (last) document from a collection.

```
> db.Sports.find().sort({'_id':-1}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb60b1dea65504b456ab14"), "Type" : "F1", "Head" : "Ferrari Lost Championship", "Body" : "By two positions, Ferrari loses the F1 Championship, leaving the Italians in tears." }
```

Answer (score 20):

> I need a query with constant time response

By default, the indexes in MongoDB are B-Trees. Searching a B-Tree is a O(logN) operation, so even `find({_id:...})` will not provide constant time, O(1) responses.

That stated, you can also sort by the `_id` if you are using `ObjectId` for you IDs. [See here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125521/). Of course, even that is only good to the last second.

You may to resort to "writing twice". Write once to the main collection and write again to a "last updated" collection. Without transactions this will not be perfect, but with only one item in the "last updated" collection it will always be fast.

Comment: I see a lot of noSQL and MongoDB solutions advocating "writing twice", mostly for count holders when the size of data becomes very large. I'm guessing this is common practice?

Comment: MongoDB does not flush to disk very often and it has no transactions, so writes become significantly faster. The trade-off here is that you are encouraged to de-normalize data which often leads to multiple writes. Of course, if you get 10x or 100x write throughput (which I've seen), then 2x or 3x the writes is still a big improvement.

Comment: Searching in B-Tree is not O(logN) operation, that's in BinarySearchTree where left values are smaller than the right values and the root node value, this is not the case in BinaryTree. for B-Tree it is still O(N), N = number of nodes.

Comment: @NaveenKumar The Wikipedia entry literally describes search as O(log n). In both worst and average cases. It's literally a 50-year old algorithm. Are you bringing something new here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: @GatesVP That B-Tree article you are providing is different from what I thought. That's why it is like that. By B-Tree I thought you were saying `Binary-Tree`. The very first line in the article you provided says: `NOT TO BE CONFUSED WITH BINARY TREE OR B+ TREE`. If it was a binary tree, then it would surely be O(N) for searching a node in it.

Answer (score 2):

php7.1 mongoDB:
`$data = $collection->findOne([],['sort' => ['_id' => -1],'projection' => ['_id' => 1]]);`

Answer (score 1):

My Solution :

`db.collection("name of collection").find({}, {limit: 1}).sort({$natural: -1})`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto-generated Mongo Object Ids in your document, it contains timestamp in it as first 4 bytes using which latest doc inserted into the collection could be found out. I understand this is an old question, but if someone is still ending up here looking for one more alternative.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
[{$group: {_id: null, latestDocId: { $max: "$_id"}}}, {$project: {_id: 0, latestDocId: 1}}])
```

Above query would give the *_id* for the latest doc inserted into the collection

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get the **last** record from all MongoDB documents from the "foo" collection.(change foo,x,y.. etc.)

```
db.foo.aggregate([{$sort:{ x : 1, date : 1 } },{$group: { _id: "$x" ,y: {$last:"$y"},yz: {$last:"$yz"},date: { $last : "$date" }}} ],{   allowDiskUse:true  })
```

you can add or remove from the group

help articles: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/

Answer (score 1):

Mongo CLI syntax:

```
db.collectionName.find({}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Let Mongo create the ID, it is an auto-incremented hash

mymongo:
self._collection.find().sort("_id",-1).limit(1)