# How to improve performance when retrieving the last document from a collection

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Here is a statement where `Limit()` precedes `Sort()`...

```
var result Candle
dao.c.Find(bson.M{"symbol": "USD"}).Limit(1).Sort("-time").One(&result);
```

... and here is a statement where `Limit()` comes after `Sort()`:

```
var result Candle
dao.c.Find(bson.M{"symbol": "USD"}).Sort("-time").Limit(1).One(&result);
```

Is there any performance difference between the statements above?

Comment: Why are they logically equivalent?

Comment: I was reading the following thread and to me it looked like the order makes a difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920651/get-the-latest-record-from-mongodb-collection

Comment: it seems you should use sort before limit https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/#limit-the-number-of-query-results-to-reduce-network-demand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might answer regarding the `mgo` package and MongoDB itself.

### In `mgo`

The [`Query.Limit()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Limit) and [`Query.Sort()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Sort) methods just operate on the [`Query`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query) object locally, and once you setup the query, you execute it e.g. with [`Query.One()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.One) or [`Query.All()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.One). The order in which you called the methods to set it up is not stored and does not matter.

### In MongoDB

Quoting from [MongoDB doc: Combine Cursor Methods:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods)

> The following statements chain cursor methods [`limit()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) and [`sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort):
>
> ```
> db.bios.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).limit( 5 )
> db.bios.find().limit( 5 ).sort( { name: 1 } )
> ```
>
> **The two statements are equivalent**; i.e. the order in which you chain the [`limit()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) and the [`sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort) methods is not significant. Both statements return the first five documents, as determined by the ascending sort order on ‘name’.

---

So there is no difference, they are equivalent and thus have the same performance.