# Get latest document inserted in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

How do I get the latest document inserted in (a standalone, no RS) MongoDb over existing collections?

And how do I get all documents inserted after this document?

Comment: Over existing collections, if it means latest document across collections it cannot be done in mongodb. For getting the latest document in a single collection, please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920651/get-the-latest-record-from-mongodb-collection/21516477

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done only in replica set. Please follow [the tutorial to convert standalone instance to replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/).

You can get a reference to the last inserted document from [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/):

```
db.oplog.rs.find({op:"i"}).sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1);
```

`ns` field contains name of the database and collection, and `o._id` contains the object's identifier.

To get references to documents that were inserted after that later you can use `ts` field of the document you retrieved in the previous query:

```
db.oplog.rs.find({op:"i", ts: {$gt: last.ts}});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I get an empty output. I'm `dbOwner`.

Comment: I updated the initial question for standalone MongoDb if this is causing the empty log.

Comment: Updated the answer. There is nothing you can do without replica set.

Comment: If your oplog appears always empty, make sure you are checking the right collection, which is under the ```local``` database

Answer (score 1):

This command will cause MongoDB to load everything to memory, if oplog.rs is very big, then it will cause memory usage high

```
db.oplog.rs.find({op:"i"}).sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1);
```

Comment: Please use markdown for code blocks