# Node.js Mongodb collection.countDocuments callback not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, node-mongodb-native

I am attempting to write a Node.js app that gets the most recently added item in a particular MongoDB collection, using MongoDB Node.js Driver 3.4.  As I understand it, the way to do so is to use collection.countDocuments to pass the number of documents into a callback, make a cursor that skips that number - 1, then call a function to actually return the document.  My problem is that the callback to collection.countDocuments never seems to actually run.

My code, including console.log calls for debugging:

```
    mongo.connect(dburl, (err, client) => {
        console.log("Attempting to connect to database");
        if(err) {
            console.log("Couldn't connect to server");
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            var heatdata;
            try {
                var db = client.db(dbname);
                console.log("Database: " + db.databaseName);
                var dbo = db.collection(colName);
                console.log("Collection: " + dbo.collectionName);
                dbo.countDocuments({}, function(err,count) {
                    console.log("Count");
                    if (err) throw err;
                    dbo.find({}).skip(count - 1).toArray((err, docs) => {
                        console.log("Made it to skip");
                        if (err) {
                            res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                            res.write('<h1>Error on accessing database information.</h1>');
                            console.log("Couldn't get the requested document");
                            res.end();
                            throw err;
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Result: " + docs);
                            heatdata = docs;
                            console.log("In method: " + heatdata);
                        }
                    });
                    console.log("Past the find");
                });
                console.log("Past the count");
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.log("Error caught: " + e.name);
                throw e.message;
            }
            console.log("Out of method: " + heatdata);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.write(heatdata);
            res.end();
        }
    });
```

Expected console output:

```
Attempting to connect to database
Database: myDatabase
Collection: myCollection
Count
Made it to skip
Result: {foo:bar}
In method: {foo:bar}
Past the find
Past the count
Out of method: {foo:bar}
```

Actual output:

```
Attempting to connect to database
Database: myDatabase
Collection: myCollection
Past the count
Out of method: undefined
TypeError: First argument must be string or Buffer
```

In other words, none of the code from dbo.countDocuments is running at all, including the first log statement indicating that it even entered the callback in the first place.  What might be going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: the traceback is as follows:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:642:11)
at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:617:10)
at mongo.connect (C:\Netshare\heatgraph.js:72:21)
at result (C:\Netshare\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:414:17)
at executeCallback (C:\Netshare\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:406:9)
at err (C:\Netshare\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:286:5)
at connectCallback (C:\Netshare\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:241:5)
at process.nextTick (C:\Netshare\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:463:7)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Note that when I comment out the `countDocuments` block and replace it with `dbo.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1}).next(callback);`, I get the exact same traceback.

Edit 2: So when I ran the original code snipped outside of the http listener I had it in, it delivered this console output:

```
Attempting to connect to database
Connection: true
Database: faketemps
Collection: temps
Past the count
Out of array method: undefined
Connection: true
Count
Past the find
Made it to skip
Result: [object Object]
In array method: [object Object]
```

So basically, the reason the callback didn't seem to be running was that I hadn't given it enough time to actually run.  I'll try wrapping this all in a `setInterval` to give it a few attempts to actually get something and then time out at an appropriate point in time.  Regardless, lesson officially learned on asynchronous programming.

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920651/get-the-latest-record-from-mongodb-collection/21516477 . It's better way to get the latest item from a collection. Your method doesn't guarantee you will get the latest item, because there can be any operation on collection between `countDocuments` and `find` queries.

Comment: So in other words, by using two lines to get my document, I leave a space where a document can be added after I get the count but before I actually get the document?  I don't know that that will be a problem for what I'm working on specifically, but in general terms this is quite helpful moving forward.  Unfortunately, having just tried doing so with `dbo.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1}).next(function...)`, the callback in `next` is still getting skipped, so the problem must be elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Sorry, what is `next` method? You should do this way `dbo.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... })`

Answer (score 1):

The countDocuments function is used like this :

```
dbo.countDocuments(requestObj, options, callback)
```

The second argument is the option argument (See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/ for more details).

Hope that will help.