# How do I sort new items by newest?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this nodeJS code but whenever I post my data, the newest data is added on the end instead of start. I tried adding  `Crud.find().sort('_id', -1).exec((err, data) =>` but it still doesn't work.

```
app.get('/v2/posts', (req,res) => {
    Crud.find((err, data)=> {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920651/get-the-latest-record-from-mongodb-collection/53474483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try-

```
Crud.find().sort({$natural:-1})
```