# How to sort a collection by date in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Node.JS. I have a collection which contains a date and other rows. The date is a JavaScript `Date` object.

How can I sort this collection by date?

Comment: simple , 
collection.find().sort({datefield: 1}, function(err, cursor){...});

or you can also use

collection.find().sort({datefield: -1}, function(err, cursor){...});

Comment: Note that you might not need a `date` column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125521/uses-for-mongodb-objectid-creation-time

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Just a slight modification to @JohnnyHK answer

```
collection.find().sort({datefield: -1}, function(err, cursor){...});
```

In many use cases we wish to have latest records to be returned (like for latest updates / inserts).

Comment: What do you intend to put in the function? Just trying to sort on `Date` objects without a function is not working for me on 2.6.3.

Comment: @SamBrightman That function is just a callback. Whatever you want to do with the query result, you put that logic inside your callback. You can read more on what callbacks are and how they work to learn event based programming.

Comment: Sure, I know what a callback is. I only saw the sorting requirement in the question and all the answers give callbacks. At the same time, sorting wasn't working for me, so I thought maybe you have to do additional work in the function.

Comment: @SamBrightman Oh ok. For convenience you can be explicit and chain like `collection.find().sort(...).exec(function(err, cursor) {})`

Comment: it says sort() only takes 1 Argument

Answer (score 96):

```
db.getCollection('').find({}).sort({_id:-1})
```

This will sort your collection in descending order based on the date of insertion

Comment: Thanks! This is the best/simplest solution so far!

Comment: This should be the accepted aswer, because a date field is redundant with _id (Proper ObjectId)

Comment: @MaxO. No, this answer actually fails if you have a custom `_id`.  The selected answer is more exact and robust.

Comment: This works with pagination ^

Answer (score 49):

Sorting by date doesn't require anything special. Just sort by the desired date field of the collection.

Updated for the 1.4.28 node.js native driver, you can sort ascending on `datefield` using any of the following ways:

```
collection.find().sort({datefield: 1}).toArray(function(err, docs) {...});
collection.find().sort('datefield', 1).toArray(function(err, docs) {...});
collection.find().sort([['datefield', 1]]).toArray(function(err, docs) {...});
collection.find({}, {sort: {datefield: 1}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {...});
collection.find({}, {sort: [['datefield', 1]]}).toArray(function(err, docs) {...});
```

`'asc'` or `'ascending'` can also be used in place of the `1`.

To sort descending, use `'desc'`, `'descending'`, or `-1` in place of the `1`.

Comment: I am applying above solution on username field, It's working fine but it is case sensitive How to ignore it?

Comment: Right answer with multi way (y)

Answer (score 16):

Sushant Gupta's answers are a tad bit outdated and don't work anymore.

The following snippet should be like this now :

`collection.find({}, {"sort" : ['datefield', 'asc']} ).toArray(function(err,docs) {});`

Comment: @JohnnyHK Sweet. I don't remember the exact scenario, but last summer I was trying to get the sort to work with Sushant's snippet and it just wasn't working for me. Perhaps it is because it was lacking the `toArray` part.

Comment: This is actually a wrong answer, it gives wrong result in node.js

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
collection.find({}, {"sort" : [['datefield', 'asc']]}, function (err, docs) { ... });
```

Using Node.js, Express.js, and Monk

Answer (score 7):

```
collection.find().sort('date':1).exec(function(err, doc) {});
```

this worked for me

referred https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/query/

Answer (score 6):

With mongoose it's as simple as:

```
collection.find().sort('-date').exec(function(err, collectionItems) {
  // here's your code
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Additional Square **[ ]** Bracket is required for sorting parameter to work.

```
collection.find({}, {"sort" : [['datefield', 'asc']]} ).toArray(function(err,docs) {});
```

Answer (score 3):

if your date format is like this : 14/02/1989 ----> you may find some problems

you need to use ISOdate  like this :

```
var start_date = new Date(2012, 07, x, x, x);
```

-----> the result ------>ISODate("2012-07-14T08:14:00.201Z")

now just use the query like this :

```
 collection.find( { query : query ,$orderby :{start_date : -1}} ,function (err, cursor) {...}
```

that's it :)

Answer (score 2):

With mongoose I was not able to use 'toArray', and was getting the error: `TypeError: Collection.find(...).sort(...).toArray is not a function.`
The toArray function exists on the Cursor class from the Native MongoDB NodeJS driver ([reference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray)).

Also sort accepts only one parameter, so you can't pass your function inside it.

This worked for me (as answered by [Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33223694/7145177)):

```
collection.find().sort('-date').exec(function(error, result) {
  // Your code
})
```