# Querying for farthest timestamp

Tags: mongodb, scala, time, casbah, querying

How can I search my `mongodb` database for the document with the farthest `timestamp`? `Timestamp` being a date, `ISODate` format or not.

Comment: Consider playing around `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`. It should be less resource utilizing then aggregating `MAX` through all the records. Also look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847766/how-to-sort-a-collection-by-date-in-mongodb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ISODate format you can use `$max` in aggregate query to get oldest date.

Refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/