# How to Sort the MongoDB data using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

var query = { "to": req.params.id };
    var mysort = { receivedDate: 1 };

```
Message.find(query, (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.json(doc);
    } else {
        res.json(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a collection by date in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847766/how-to-sort-a-collection-by-date-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is like the following:

```
db.collecttionName.find().sort({date:1});
```

But instead of date, you can pass in other criteria.