# Get n most recent documents based on objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am wondering if there is a way to order a result set based on the date component in an object Id

```
myCol.find().sort('_id descending').limit(5).select('title _id').exec(function(e, data){
     res.render('some-page.html',{data:data});
});
```

I don't have an explicit date field in my documents, but it's my understanding that objectId already contains a date component, so I am wondering if I can take advantage of that here.

The above code will not correctly order the result set

EDIT:
By updating the query slightly I got it to work

```
myCol.find().sort([['_id', -1]])
```

Source: [uses for mongodb ObjectId creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125521/uses-for-mongodb-objectid-creation-time)

Comment: Yes that works. So what are you actually asking here? How to query from a point in time?

Comment: Generally speaking, since an ObjectId is "monotonic" the values always increase and they "should" be the most recent. The timestamp part is the "prefix" 4 bytes in hex. It does not change, so it is a marker of "insertion time". You can always use [$natural](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) for the sort, but this is really a representation of where the documents "reside" rather than when they were inserted. Works as designed. I don't see the problem here. Perhaps you need to explain more in your question or really look at the results further.

Comment: Seems like all I had to do was tweak the argument passed to sort(). If I pass an array it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to sort descending with Mongoose is to prefix the field name in your call so [`sort`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) with a `-`:

```js
myCol.find()
     .sort('-_id')
     .limit(5)
     .select('title _id')
     .exec(function(e, data){
         res.render('some-page.html',{data:data});
     });
```

Comment: @TGH Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: Yes I am using mongoose

Comment: @TGH Ok cool, I also updated the answer for Mongoose.  There are [lots of ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825520/in-mongoose-how-do-i-sort-by-date-node-js/15081087#15081087) to pass parameters to `sort`.